# Visibility:Hidden - How to do this in Firefox?

Tags: css, html-table, border, visibility, hidden

I have been reading these forums for some time, but this is my first question :)

The question is related to styling tables. If you look at my page in Chrome, at the bottom left of my table and the bottom left `<td>` tag, I was able to hide the borders the using `visibility:hidden;` But, in Firefox, the `<td>` still shows these borders. I have found that Firefox doesn't like the `visibility` attribute.

http://allramhosting.com/new/shared-3/

```
.hide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

<td class="hide">&nbsp; </td>
```

Does anyone know a way around this that will work in multiple browsers? I also tried border-color:white; in the `<td>` on `<tfoot>` and that almost works; it keeps the very bottom border line visible.

Comment: try display:none instead, this means it's not rendered visible, and doesn't take up space instead of just invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
.hide { border-style: none; }
```

or

```
.hide { border: none; }
```

on your `td`s or

```
.tableClass{ border: none;}
```

if your table has class `tableClass`.

Comment: that worked, except now i cant get the very bottom border to come back even when i apply to the class - border-bottom:1px; border-color:black;

Comment: `border: none; ` actually sets `border-style: none; `. You can get your bottom border back with `border-bottom-style: solid; `. 
You can also group your 3 settings and write `border-bottom: 1px solid black`. Hth!

Comment: thank you that works nicely :) its strange in chrome the bottom border is like 3px thick but in firefox it shows as 1px... strangeness

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the border-width to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
display:none
```

I find that works to hide things far better without side effects.

As an FYI I have found issues with proper size rendering when you start hiding "parts" of tables.   Meaning that I have seen the browser (including chrome) not render the rest of the document properly or hang things off the end of the document when you hide parts of a table.  If you hide the whole table it seems to figure that out fine.

Comment: For this situation, getting ride of the `<td>` altogether would seem like a better option than `display:none;`

Comment: Or the entire table.  I've found hiding TD's to be very buggy across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I once worked around with the following trick:
Depends upon what you want to achieve in styling, but generally, setting relevant element's (color/background-color/border-color(in this case)) to 'transparent' usually works across browsers.

hope this helps someone.